# can't login to virtual machine in proxmox due to special sign in password (alma linux)

Tags: proxmox

Friends of the forum, I feel desperate trying to solve this problem.
Yesterday I had to make a backup of a server that was hacked. This server is called primary.
When I got hacked, I set up a new server called primary-new and started from scratch with the account backups.
These servers are assigned the same ip address, so in order to recover certain things, I had to stop the primary-new server and just turn on the old "primary" server to prevent the ips from colliding.
What happened, that after I started the server again, it was without internet connection and I can't access by ssh, also I have all my sites down.
This happened to me the first time I installed the server and it was an error with the NetworkManager.
Now, if I manage to enter through the console using proxmox I could fix everything.
My problem that the password I assigned to the server has a special sign.
"591d<u9 "I£90"
Damn sign. I have not been able to get it.
I can't copy it either because the proxmox shell is a stream from the monitor of that virtual machine itself and it's not connected to your computer's keyboard.
Any way to make that sign through OPENVNC of proxmox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more obvious solutions are:

1. Change the password to something you can type by booting in single user mode (assumng that the OS is configured to NOT prompt for a password in single user mode)
2. Since you seem to be able to render the characters outside the NoVNC console session, then do so and use some tool to send the keystrokes to the NoVNC window (yes, the mechanism is very vague but you told us NOTHING about the client you are using nor the OS on the VM - from a client using X, you could use xdotool, on MS-Windows, auto-it and VBA have the capability)
3. Use the compose key functionality - again how you do this depends on the OS. From Linux:

- press and hold [ctrl] + [shift] + [u]
- release [u]
- enter the UTF-8 hex code of the symbol you want to type
- release [ctrl] + [shift]

4. Assuming this is a Linux/Unix VM, [configure the console to use a serial port](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/how-to-enter-a-vm-from-the-the-node-console.55323/) rather than a frame buffer and connect from the shell on the hypervisor acessed via ssh (then just paste the password)
5. Use a virtual keyboard with the desired layout. e.g. florence on Linux at your client
6. Wipe the new VM and start again (provisioning platforms *should* be easy and quick)

> These servers are assigned the same ip address

....another reason for having seperate management / service NICs and using a load balancer for the service traffic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
It worked by trying many things and it was Altgr+May+3 that worked for me.

Comment: Also, worth mentioning you *can* run them both side by side by putting in disjoint networks (say create additional VM bridge and put other machine there) and even connect using intermediate (virtual) machine with fancy NAT configuration. While undesirable for a long term, such a configuration is acceptable for a period of migration.